# Can I connect my own hardware to a universal 2.4GHz RF wireless receiver?

Tags: rf, wireless, keyboard

I built a USB keyboard for PC with a microcontroller, and it works great.
The next challenge is to do it wirelessly.

I have seen that sell **universal** 2.4GHz RF to USB wireless receivers, similar to this image:
[image]

On the keyboard side, I must use an RF module, to communicate with the receiver, mentioned above.
But I can't find information on how to pair with that device and what protocol they use.

Any comments or suggestions are welcome

**Update**
I think I'm looking for this:
[USB to wireless to USB… Is it possible?](https://superuser.com/questions/119056/usb-to-wireless-to-usb-is-it-possible)

**Update 2**
I think the most practical thing, to avoid building a USB receiver on the PC side, is to use a dongle, Bluetooth to USB.

Comment: There's no such thing as an universal receiver. You will need to read the datasheet of the device you're referring to. It will list the things it works with, or it's plain and simple snake oil.

Comment: Anyway "tell me a compatible transformer to this receiver“ is product recommendation question. I've seen these getting closed here, as rule. I think you need to read the datasheet and ask technical question based on understanding that, or about understanding datasheet

Comment: Ok, if so, I would have to create on the USB side of the PC, my own receiver hardware.

Comment: Can you find a receiver with a published datasheet and post a link to the datasheet? That will help us determine what you would need at the other end. The SuperUser question you have linked to is looking for communication between two PCs. Your application is much simpler as it is might just be one-way.

Comment: Check open source keyboards, some of them include a wireless module. You don't need USB to USB, you need a device that abstracts the wireless link (usually Bluetooth or proprietary link)  and enumerates as an HID.